# How to add array to useState array after component mount React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have updated this question.

I can't figure out why the setDailyTotals useState Hook is not being called at the end of the CalculateTotals function. setDailyTotals appears to be called when the component mounts but never gets called again after that.

Basically What I am trying to do is sum up of the field values i.e numberOfAdults, numberOfKids, moneyIn for each day and display each day tta

Sorry If I'm missing something simple and I would really appreciate any help, Thank you.

```
export const TabBar = () => {
  const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState(0);
  const forms = GetForms();
  const [dailyTotals, setDailyTotals] = useState([]);
  debugger;

  useEffect(() => {
    debugger;
    if (forms.length !== 0) {
      CalculateTotals();
    }
  }, [forms]);

  const CalculateTotals = () => {
    //This Function is used to calculate how many adults, kids were in on a given day
    //It will also calculate the total money taken in for each day too.

    let totalNumberOfAdults = 0;
    let totalNumberOfChildren = 0;
    let totalMoneyIn = 0;
    let selectedFormDate = moment().format("llll");
    let dayTotal = {};
    let totals = [];

    debugger;

    forms.forEach(form => {
      if (moment(form.timeIn).isSame(selectedFormDate, "day")) {
        // if the date on the form is the same as the selectedFormDate
        // Then add the below counts from the form to a local count variable.

        // repeat this process until the form date does not match the selected form date
        // which then indicates, the loop is iterating over a different day.
        // when that happens, else will be triggered.
        totalNumberOfAdults += parseInt(form.numberOfAdults || 0);
        totalNumberOfChildren += form.children.length || 0;
        totalMoneyIn += form.totalGroupPrice || 0;
      } else {
        // when the loop has started iterating over a different day
        // take the local count variables i.e totalNumberOfAdults etc, add them to an Object
        // add that object to an array called Daily totals then reset all the local variables

        dayTotal = {
          date: selectedFormDate,
          totalNumberOfAdults,
          totalNumberOfChildren,
          totalMoneyIn
        };
        totalNumberOfAdults = 0;
        totalNumberOfChildren = 0;
        totalMoneyIn = 0;

        if (dayTotal.totalNumberOfChildren !== 0) {
          //Todo figure out how to push new item to use state array

          // setDailyTotals(dailyTotals => [...dailyTotals, dayTotal]);
          // setDailyTotals(prevState => ({ prevState, dayTotal }));
          totals.push(dayTotal);
          dayTotal = {};
        }

        // after adding object to array, reset counts, its important to add
        // totals for the currently iterated day to local counts again, to continue the tally.
        totalNumberOfAdults += parseInt(form.numberOfAdults || 0);
        totalNumberOfChildren += form.children.length || 0;
        totalMoneyIn += form.totalGroupPrice || 0;

        // now that the form date is no longer the same as the selectedFormDate
        // selectedFormDate must be changed to match the now current form Date
        selectedFormDate = moment(form.timeIn);

        console.log("totals: ", dailyTotals);
      }
    });
    // at the end of the loop, when all of the forms have been iterated
    // close off, and add the final day to the object and add to array.
    dayTotal = {
      date: selectedFormDate,
      totalNumberOfAdults,
      totalNumberOfChildren,
      totalMoneyIn
    };
    totalNumberOfAdults = 0;
    totalNumberOfChildren = 0;
    totalMoneyIn = 0;
    
    
    totals.push(dayTotal);
    dayTotal = {};
    console.log("totals 2:", totals);
    
    

    //State Array
    setDailyTotals(totals);
    console.log("dailyTotalsStateArray: ", dailyTotals);
  };

if (forms.length === 0)
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>No Records</h2>
      </div>
    );

  return (
    <>
      <Paper>
        <Tabs
          value={setSelectedTab}
          onChange={handleChange}
          indicatorColor={"primary"}
          textColor={"primary"}>
          <Tab label={"Records"} />
          <Tab label={"Totals"} />
        </Tabs>
      </Paper>

      {selectedTab === 0 && <RecordTable forms={forms} />}
      {selectedTab === 1 && <TotalsCountTable forms={dailyTotals} />}
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Console.log output]

Comment: Why you are spreading array to object. Is there any specific requirement to typecast them in object?

Comment: What happens if you use the commented-out code `setDailyTotals(prevState => [...prevState, dayTotal]);`?

Comment: I spread the array because that's what I thought i had to do from the other solution. I've taken that out now. I just want to display the number of adults, kids money in per day, one day per row. At the moment I thought an array of objects would work.

Comment: @DylanSp still just has an array with just the first object in it.

Comment: When you loop over data and `setDailyTotals(totals);` within, you queue up a bunch of state updates that all overwrite the previous update, this is why you only see a single element added to the array. You *should* do a functional state update for *every* `setDailyTotals` queued in the callback.

Comment: It's because useState is not synchronous and your console.log is showing you last state of ```dailyTotals```

Comment: what does GetForms do?  In looking at the code I see why CalculateTotals is only called once (and hence the setDailTotals hook).

Comment: @terpinmd GetForm makes a get request to firebase firestore which returns an array of objects from a collection in firestore.

Comment: Can you move `CalculateTotals` inside the `useEffect` to avoid the possible out of sync closure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've seen this before. You have two instances of TabBar, and the setDailyTotals that "isn't working" is actually setting the state in the previous instance of TabBar, not the current one.

With Functional Components, re-rendering means destroying the previous instance of the component and creating a new one.

UseEffect happens after rendering is done.

Updating state from within UseEffect will update the state of TabBar, but then causes a re-render which the new instance of TabBar doesn't get the update.

tl;dr Remove useEffect, don't wrap most of your code in `const CalculateTotals` but instead run it directly within the same-render.  To prevent lots or even infinite re-renders, call GetForms from outside this component and pass it in via props. (Use a wrapper component that displays either TabBar if forms.length > 0 or some default placeholder component otherwise.) The alternative to the wrapper component is a more thorough version of `if (forms.length !== 0)` which early-returns a placeholder.

Or, move CalculateTotals outside of any component, `function CalculateTotals(form) { ...`, and initialize your state to that... if you even need useState anymore: `const [dailyTotals, setDailyTotals] = useState(CalculateTotals(form));`

As an aside, I know what a "tabbar" is, but this code that produces this report doesn't seem like it belongs in a "tabbar" with a hook called "setSelectedTab".  Maybe pull out the report into its own component, which TabBar calls for this job, simplifying things, and your issue may shake out on its own.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  const forms = GetForms();

  // ...

  useEffect(() => {
    debugger;
    if (forms.length !== 0) {
      CalculateTotals();
    }
  }, [forms]);
```

Looks like the `forms` variable didn't change. The way react checks if a dependency was changed is by referential equality. So if the forms variable always refer to the same array, the useEffect will never be triggered again, even if some element were pushed/removed or if the internal elements of the array changed.

If you are only pushing/removing element from the array, a fix would be to add the length as a dependency:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    debugger;
    if (forms.length !== 0) {
      CalculateTotals();
    }
  }, [forms, forms.length]);
```